# Why do people say “no offense” when starting a sentence?

Tags: phrases, idioms, phrase-usage

I know what “no offense” means, but I don’t think I fully understand its usage. I’ve seen many people saying it before they say something insulting. But does including “no offense” make the statement less offensive? I don’t really get why people use it...

Comment: I think it has more to do with the recipient becoming more recipient of the message due to the deliberate choice of acting less defensively. Not sure what the exact *psychology* behind it is.

Comment: I think that starting with "no offense" is simply acknowledging that the speaker is aware that what follows may cause offense and is hoping to tone down the reaction.

Comment: Thank you for the comment!

Comment: "With all due respect"... expect to be disrespected.

Comment: probably more appropriate in http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, if you are getting your English from Big Bang, you should be aware that they have many examples of usage which might be common, but are not quite right. Penny says stuff all the time like: "I am _literally_ dying to go there".

Comment: My unsympathetic reading of the phrase "no offense" is that its user is trying to pre-emptively escape blame for saying something obviously offensive.

Comment: @KillingTime When trying to hold a rational discussion about a sensitive topic, facts to which someone may take offense may sometimes be required to continue the discussion. In that situation, the "no offense" can mean "I'm not trying to go nuclear here, but we need to consider this too". Flame wars start far too easily on the internet, so you are likely to find the term more common there than in face to face conversation.

Comment: In England, it can be literal, meaning 'excuse me saying this blunt thing'. But at times it's the English reversal thing going on and it announces 'I am being deliberately offensive'. As in 'no offense intended - but you clearly have no idea about this subject!' It's similar to 'with respect'... which seemingly mild term quite often means 'you are a dunderhead sir! and I'm about to put you straight!'  If someone uses either of these terms in England they can be quite upset, but not showing it, to the extent that fisticuffs might be coming up soon. I agree with user888379

Comment: @Jelila That all applies to AmE as well. Same damn thing.

Comment: Oh, right! @lambie

Answer (score 3):

"No offense" is short for "No offense intended." I'm adding this answer because it wasn't explicitly stated in the comments and someone reading the question might not get the full idea: It means "I'm going to speak bluntly but don't mean to hurt you by saying it." Even so, as user 888379 indicates, it might not be said sincerely.